# How to forward multiple constructor arguments through a variadic template to an array initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to pass multiple initializer lists through a variadic template to construct an std::array in place.

However I fail to find a version that compiles (C++17).

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct TwoInts {
  TwoInts(int x, int y) 
    : a{x}
    , b{y}
  {}
  int a,b;
};

template<typename T, int S>
struct Holder {
  template<typename... Args>
  Holder(Args&&... args) : m({{std::forward<Args>(args)...}}) {}

  //Deleted for clarity of the example:
  Holder(const Holder& o) = delete;
  Holder(Holder&& o) = delete;
  std::array<T,S> m;
};
```

We can perform the following initializations:

```cpp
TwoInts a = {1,2};
std::array<TwoInts,1> b{{{1,2}}};
std::array<TwoInts,2> c{{{1,2},{3,4}}};

Holder<int,1> d{1};
Holder<int,2> e{1,2};
```

But how to modify the example to make this work?

```
Holder<TwoInts,1> f{{{1,2}}};
Holder<TwoInts,2> f{{{1,2},{3,4}}};
```

Gcc and clang fail find a matching constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be explicit about the argument types instead of implicitly passing `std::initializer_list`s:

```
Holder<TwoInts,1> f{TwoInts{1, 2}};
Holder<TwoInts,2> e{TwoInts{1,2}, TwoInts{3,4}};
```

This is due to `std::initializer_list`s that produce a so-called "non-deduced" context, so you cannot use `std::initializer_list`s to pass them to a template constructor (as the language doesn't allow you to explicitly nail down the template types of a constructor template).

Note that in `std::array<TwoInts,1> b{{{1,2}}};` you don't use `std::initializer_list`, but instead perform aggregate initialization, and in `Holder<int,1> d{1};`, you just pass an `int`, which works fine with deduction.

---

If `TwoInt` objects aren't move/copy constructible, you could turn them into an aggregate;

```
struct TwoInts {
   TwoInts(const TwoInts&) = delete;
   TwoInts(TwoInts&&) = delete;

   int a,b;
};
```

and then use aggregate initialization throughout. The holder constructor should look like this;

```
template<typename... Args>
   Holder(Args&&... args) : m{{std::forward<Args>(args)...}} {}
   //                        ^ no parentheses  ... neither ^
```

and you can initialize with

```
Holder<TwoInts,1> f{1, 2};
Holder<TwoInts,2> e{1,2, 3,4};
```

Comment: True, that works, but it relies on `TwoInts` being either move or copy constructible, thus sidesteps the problem somewhat. What if that is not the case?

Comment: @RedundantEntry See the edit. I don't have a solution in mind that work for both cases though.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that would work. Of course, that again makes an assumption on the element type `TwoInts`. But I guess there is no way to make this work without that.